# can't connect to my 2nd router that has dhcp off - TP-Link archer c5

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

i have 2 tp-link archer c5 routers

the setup is as such: ISP modem > Archer c5#1 > 8 port switch > archer c5 #2

the address to c5#1 is 192.168.1.1
the address to c5#2 is 192.168.2.1

c5#2 has dhcp turned off

the problem is, when i connect to c5#2, i can get to the internet fine, i can even connect to c5#1 fine, but when i try to connect to c5#2 it doesn't work...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The address of c5#2 needs to be 192.168.1.x. (I'd make it 192.168.1.2 personally)

192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 are different networks.